# Guest user cannot access a SharePoint Site using MS Graph Explorer

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

A guest user (user1) with a Office 365 Family account has been added to a SharePoint site given by an Admin having a Office 365 Business account as a group member. The guest user received the email with the SharePoint link, when clicked the guest user can open his SharePoint without any problems and access the site and all the documents libraries, folders and files.

Also, an user (user2) in the organization has been added as a group member on the same SharePoint Site.

Programmatically, using MS Graph Explorer, user2, can access and browse the SharePoint Site, its documents library, folders/files, using requests like :
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=* ,
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteId/drives, https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteId/drives/driveId/root/children, https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteId/drives/driveId/items/id/children

These requests are not available for user1...

How, programmatically, using MS Graph Explorer, user1, can access and browse the SharePoint Site, its documents library, folders/files ?

Comment: What result user1 get?

Comment: user1 cannot get a valid JSON response with a  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*,  ("code": "InternalServerError"). Which is normal I guess as user1 have only a family account and this kind of account do not includes SharePoint Sites.  user2 will get the JSON with the sites list available.